# Matplotlib twiny() axis does not have the padding the original axis has

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the following toy code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
plt.grid()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

X1 =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
X2 = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000]
Y = [0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.2]

ax1.plot(X1,Y)
ax1.set_ylim([0, 1.0])


ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
ax2.set_xticks(X2)

ax1.set_xlabel('X1 Label')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax2.set_xlabel('X2 Label')

plt.show()
```

Which gives the following plot:

[image]

As one can see, the `X1` axis has a padding at the end (where the `10` is located). However, the second axis `X2` stops at the end of the actual graph, which is not desired.

Basically, I want the `10000` value aligned with the `10`, ending in the same place with that padding.

The answer in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418191/twiny-axis-not-aligned-to-lower-axis-matplotlib) does not help me because I am already doing what it was suggested (adding the `set_xlim` for the `twiny()` axis).

Also (albeit not as important as the original question), I would like to know why Matplotlib decided to plot all the x ticks on the `X2` axis instead of "jumping" a few ones just like on the `X1` axis.

Comment: If you want the axes to sync then use ax.secondary_axis not twin.

Comment: @JodyKlymak I don't have a function (nor its inverse) for the data I have and that is needed for `secondary_axis` (if I understood it correctly).

Comment: You have the data, and that can be used as a function using interpolation.  There is an example in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`connect()`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html#the-axes-class) the bottom and top axes by using the `ax1.xlim_changed` callback to trigger `ax2.set_xlim()`.

**Update:** To restore padding on the axes limits, you can use something like this `lim()` function (default 5%):

```py
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

X1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
X2 = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000]
Y = [0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.2]

ax1.plot(X1, Y)
ax1.set_ylim([0, 1.0])

# add axes margins by `pad` percent
def lim(x, pad=5):
    xmin, xmax = min(x), max(x)
    margin = (xmax - xmin) * pad/100
    return xmin - margin, xmax + margin

ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax1.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', lambda ax1: ax2.set_xlim(*lim(X2)))
ax1.set_xlim(*lim(X1)) # trigger the xlim_changed callback
```

[image: connected ax1/ax2 with margins]

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for :) With this solution, do you know how can I bring back that white space margin I had beforehand? I tried using `plt.margin(0.05)` but to no avail.

Comment: @ihavenoidea i think you have to manually calculate the padding in this case (updated with an example `lim()` function)

Answer (score 0):

The two axis are completely separate and X2 will not just automatically align with the X1 axis when you change the ticks on an empty plot on your secondary axis.

if you plot a second line on X2 instead they will align

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

plt.grid()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

X1 =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
X2 = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000]
Y = [0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.2]

ax1.plot(X1,Y)
ax1.set_ylim([0, 1.0])

ax2 = ax1.twiny()
#ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
#ax2.set_xticks(X2)
ax2.plot(X2,Y) # Plot a second line on top of the previous one

ax1.set_xlabel('X1 Label')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax2.set_xlabel('X2 Label')

plt.show()
```

[image]

You could also do the following by using the correct xlim for X2 and remove the margin from X1 to match X2. You can probably add some margin to X2 instead some how, but I'm not sure how to do it without plotting anything on X2.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

plt.grid()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

X1 =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
X2 = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000]
Y = [0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.2]

ax1.plot(X1,Y)
ax1.set_ylim([0, 1.0])

ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax2.set_xlim(X2[0], X2[-1]) # Correct xlim for secondary axis
ax2.set_xticks(X2)
ax1.margins(0) # Remove margin from first axis to match X2

ax1.set_xlabel('X1 Label')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax2.set_xlabel('X2 Label')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Although as I tested with my real data (which is not linear), this solution appears to fail. For example, if `X2 = [3500, 4050, 4300, 5000, 5700, 6080, 7420, 8022, 9100, 9900]` it will give this [result](https://i.imgur.com/0JA6cZD.png) where neither the ticks match nor the plot itself. Do you happen to know the reason behind it?